# unpivot sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis-2012, unpivot

I have a table with logid,skilllevel,logskill    where     Data is like

```
logid, skilllevel1, skilllevel2,skilllevel3,logonskill1,logonskill2,logonskill3,

101,     90,          40,         60           1          2            3

102,      30,         20,         10           4          5            6
```

I want to get it arranged like the following:

```
logid,  skilllevel,  logonskill , skillposition

101,      90,            1           1

101,       40,           2           2

102,       30,           4           1
```

skilllevel1 corresponds to logonskill1 as so on 
skillposition is the substring of logonskill

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method is a lateral join, using `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (logid, skilllevel1, logonskill1, 1),
             (logid, skilllevel2, logonskill2, 2),
             (logid, skilllevel3, logonskill3, 3)
     ) v(logid, skilllevel, logonskill, skillposition)
where skilllevel is not null or logonskill is not null;
```

Lateral joins are very powerful.  This is just one or many things that you can do with `apply`.

Comment: thanks for the reply . I have many values in the table .. how to go about that ?

Comment: @VarunK . . . You would add additional rows for the additional columns.  Note that it is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a question.